# iOS where to release variable init outside dispatch_async block

Tags: ios, multithreading, logging

I'm implementing a file logger for the iOS app. The logger is a singleton and it has a member variable `dispatch_queue_t _queue` responsible for outputting logs to a file, so that it can ensure thread-safety and won't block the main or other threads when logs are being written.

Since the `block` takes no argument, so I cannot do `va_start` inside the block. In that case, I have to init the `message` outside the block. I'm quite new to blocks in iOS, and not sure where I should release the `message` (at `(1)` or `(2)`, and why?)

Thanks!

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];

    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        // output `message` to file

        // (1) release here?
        [message release];
    });

    // (2) or release here?
    [message release];

    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: For ARC, you should use `message = nil;` to ensure it is released.

Comment: What, no - you'd just let it go out of scope - why would you bother?

Comment: Agree. However, if there is more logic after the line, the `nil` line can release the `message` earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From Apple's documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)

> Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are
>   captured as const variables. Their values are taken at the point of
>   the block expression within the program. In nested blocks, the value
>   is captured from the nearest enclosing scope.

No need to worry about releasing message within the block. You can safely release it outside the block.

Ideally you would just convert to ARC and not worry about it.

Comment: Excellent! so in this case "message" object is retained by the block and releases when the block ends. So (2) will do it.

Answer (score 1):

(1), as you won't need `message` anymore. Highly recommend you to use ARC.

For ARC, <s>you should use `message = nil;` to ensure it is released.</s> You can also use `__weak`to avoid it being retained by the block.

Comment: You don't need to set variables to nil under ARC to ensure they are released

Comment: Agree with @powerj1984, use ARC, and memory issue of block will be quite simple. And with ARC , you (@Shivan Raptor) don't need message = nil; , because ARC will do that for you out of the run loop. Just take care of __weak and __block.

Comment: `__weak` is for ARC or not? Is it necessary to use it?

Comment: `__weak` is for ARC, if you don't need to retain the variable, use it.